# jQuery Balloon plugin position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, balloon

I'm using **jQuery Balloon** and I have a few problems with this plugin.

First of all attribute position doesn't work for me properly - it always keeps the balloon on the left top corner of my item, only the arrow changes it's direction. I need to have my balloon exactly on my object`s center or it's top center (it should be default) - not the left top corner.

Another problem is that the arrow sometimes doesn't show at all - it happens totally randomly - once on the item it's ok, but when I do it again it doesn't work - it happens totally randomly.

Sometimes my link (which is my balloon content) doesn't work. In the link as an attribute I have an information about index in array. When I click the link it changes the data in my data table - it works fine 80%. 20% of clicks doesn't reload the table - I do everything the same, it`s random.

Comment: Can you create a simple demo that reproduces the issues?  Without one, it will be hard to get help.

Comment: http://aviene.pl/stackoverflow/ - here I put part of my code where the position problem exists. I`m using d3 library here to draw some svg objects - maybe thats the problem for the position property?
Another problem here is that the Cluster info link doesn`t work. I`m using here on('click') method. I`m even checking if its on my DOM model - in my application it works randomly like I wrote yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed the whole problem with balloon library. It seems that position attribute doesn`t work well with svg elements. I still don`t know what was wrong with links inside the balloons - probably that`s the problem with the library. From time to time the click event handler didn`t work at all (still don`t know why). The solution for my problems was changing the library. Now it`s d3.tip - everything works fine :)